# SQL Oracle error - Homework Task

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me resolve the following SQL issue using Oracle Database

PROMPT:
 List all columns of the warehouse table in ascending PK sequence.
  • Only list rows where the address ends in RD or ST

```
SELECT *
FROM warehouse 
WHERE address ='% rd' 
OR WHERE address ='% st',
ORDER BY whid ASC;
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> OR WHERE address ='% st',    *
>
> Error at line 4: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: extra comma after 2nd where, and only need one `where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second `WHERE`, and the comma should be removed too. Also, you probably want to have `LIKE` before address, and you probably don't want to have the spaces.

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT *
FROM warehouse 
WHERE address LIKE '%rd' 
OR address LIKE '%st'
ORDER BY whid ASC;
```

Or, you could be clever:

```
-- You don't say this explicitly, but I think it a good idea to make sure that 
-- you are searching for rd and st in the right tense. That is why I have 'lower'
SELECT *
FROM warehouse 
WHERE lower(substr(address,-2,2)) in ('rd', 'st')
ORDER BY whid ASC;
```

Comment: is there a way to add the UPPER or LOWER attribute to the first example?

Comment: @DannyMahoney You would need to have UPPER or LOWER around both `address`'s

Comment: SELECT *
FROM warehouse 
WHERE UPPER(address ='%RD')
OR UPPER(address ='%ST')
ORDER BY whid ASC;

Creates the error

WHERE (UPPER(address ='%RD')
                     *

Error at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the second `WHERE` statement, and change your equivalence statements to `LIKE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM warehouse 
WHERE address LIKE '% rd' 
OR address LIKE '% st'
ORDER BY whid ASC;
```

If you have the equivalence statement there, you will match only strings that are exactly equal to `% rd` or `% st`.

Comment: SELECT *
'FROM warehouse 
WHERE address like '% rd' 
OR address like '% st'
ORDER BY whid ASC;'

Displays OK 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the second `WHERE`, use `LIKE` instead of `=` and try removing the space after the `%` character.

```
SELECT *
FROM warehouse 
WHERE address LIKE '%rd' 
OR address LIKE '%st'
ORDER BY whid ASC;
```

Comment: That is what I had originally and still didn't work.

[CODE]
    SELECT *
    FROM warehouse 
    WHERE address ='% rd' 
    OR address ='% st'
    ORDER BY whid ASC;
[/CODE]

Displays OK 0 Rows, but when I do the following:

    SELECT * FROM WAREHOUE

It works so the data is there

Comment: No error, but the '% st' and '% rd' syntax definitely exists in multiple occasions in the database

Comment: Use `like` as others have mentioned and make sure that there is no space after the `%` character and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Use the LIKE keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM warehouse WHERE address LIKE '%RD' OR address LIKE '%ST' ORDER BY whid ASC;
```